# Future.get() throws java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException

Tags: java, multithreading, java.util.concurrent, concurrentmodification

I have a list of recodes called filterRecords -> `List<Tuple<String, GenericRecord>> filterRecords`. I am splitting this list into sub lists and giving each sublists to a separate thread for parallel execution. My Call() method implementation returns `Tuple<List<FixedLengthRecord>, BatchDataPoints>`. But when I am doing `future.get()`, I am getting `ConcurrentModificationException`.

Below is the code snippet.

```
    ConcurrentLinkedQueue <Future<Tuple<List<FixedLengthRecord>, BatchDataPoints>>> futures = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue <>();
    List<List<Tuple<String, GenericRecord>>> partitions = new ArrayList<>();

        int partitionSize = (filterRecords.size() / fixedLengthRecordEnrichmentThreadSize);
        for (int i = 0; i < filterRecords.size(); i += partitionSize) {
            List<Tuple<String, GenericRecord>> sublist = (filterRecords.subList(i, Math.min(i + partitionSize, filterRecords.size())));
            partitions.add(sublist);
        }

        for(int fixedLengthRecordEnrichmentThread = 0; fixedLengthRecordEnrichmentThread < this.fixedLengthRecordEnrichmentThreadSize; fixedLengthRecordEnrichmentThread++) {
            futures.offer(service.submit(new FixedLengthRecordWrapper(partitions.get(fixedLengthRecordEnrichmentThread),dataEnricher)));
        }


Iterator<Future<Tuple<List<FixedLengthRecord>, BatchDataPoints>>> futureIterator = futures.iterator();
while (futureIterator.hasNext()) {
      Future<Tuple<List<FixedLengthRecord>, BatchDataPoints>> future = futureIterator.next();
      if (future.isDone() || future.isCancelled()) {
            Tuple<List<FixedLengthRecord>, BatchDataPoints> fixedLengthRecordsTuple = future.get();  // ConcurrentModificationException

      }
 }
```

I also Tried other options, like:

```
 while(!futures.isEmpty()){
   Future<Tuple<List<FixedLengthRecord>, BatchDataPoints>> future = futures.poll();
   if (future.isDone() || future.isCancelled()) {
        Tuple<List<FixedLengthRecord>, BatchDataPoints> fixedLengthRecordsTuple = future.get();
   }
 }
```

Bewlow is the stackTrace:

```
 java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
at com.data.driver.BatchCallable.processBatch(BatchCallable.java:161)
at com.data.driver.BatchCallable.call(BatchCallable.java:102)
at com.data.driver.BatchCallable.call(BatchCallable.java:38)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run$$$capture(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
 Caused by: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
at java.util.ArrayList$SubList.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:1241)
at java.util.ArrayList$SubList.size(ArrayList.java:1050)
at java.util.AbstractCollection.toArray(AbstractCollection.java:136)
at java.util.ArrayList.<init>(ArrayList.java:178)
at com.data.tranhist.fixedlength.FixedLengthRecordWrapper.getEnrichedFixedLengthRecordsFromGenericRecords(FixedLengthRecordWrapper.java:93)
at com.data.tranhist.fixedlength.FixedLengthRecordWrapper.call(FixedLengthRecordWrapper.java:63)
at com.data.tranhist.fixedlength.FixedLengthRecordWrapper.call(FixedLengthRecordWrapper.java:22)
... 5 more
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: the problem is when the `Future` is being executed - I can't see its code ...  anyway, is `futures.next()` correct?? I would expect `futureIterator.next()` !

Comment: @user16320675, check the last line of the code, I have put a comment also. I am getting exeception on future.get();

Comment: Please include the full stack trace of the exception

Comment: yes, apparently¹ an `ExecutionException` which indicates that an `Exception` (probably¹ `ConcurrentModificationException`) has occurred when executing the `Future`! [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#get()): "***Throws:** . . . `ExecutionException` - if the computation threw an exception*". I cannot see what that `Future` is doing, sorry. || **¹** without seeing the Stack Trace, I could only guess based on the title

Comment: The stack trace shows that the error originated inside the `getEnrichedFixedLengthRecordsFromGenericRecords` method.

Answer (score 1):

The subList method returns the view of the list and does not create actual list,so any structural changes in backing list will throw concurrent modification exception.

> From java doc :
> The semantics of the list returned by this method become undefined if the backing list (i.e., this list) is structurally modified in any way other than via the returned list. (Structural modifications are those that change the size of this list, or otherwise perturb it in such a fashion that iterations in progress may yield incorrect results.)
> List subList(int fromIndex, int toIndex);

In code snippet mentioned above,since the future is trying to modify the backing list (could be in dataenricher) at later point in time,it throws exception during get call